# How to replace kitchen faucet in 1993 Mobile Home

Tags: kitchen-sink

I want to replace the kitchen faucet, now there's no shut off valve (I'm thinking will have to find main valve and shut off water that way), there's no pipes, only two plastic pipes (cold and hot) coming from the bottom of the cabinet, these are attached to the old faucet. So how I will attached the hoses of the new faucet into these plastic pipes and what type of adapter, if any is required?

[image: pipes connection to old faucet]pipes coming out of the bottom of the cabinet

Comment: You will need male to male adapter of correct size, probably 1/2 inch

Comment: 1993 mobile home - gray plastic tubing? Plan on replacing **all** that polybutylene tubing before it bursts and ruins the home. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybutylene

Comment: [Polybutylene Failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybutylene#Class_action_lawsuits_and_removal_from_building_code_approved_usage)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the PB pipe disaster awaiting you (*perhaps* not if your supply isn't chlorinated - private well without a chlorinator needed) you just unscrew the connections from the old faucet and screw them onto the new faucet.

If the sizes don't match up; carry the old and new faucets to an actual hardware or plumbing store and find adapters to suit.

Plan on replacing the PB. Urgently, if you are on a chlorinated water supply.